# How can I check if a variable is a number between 0 and 999?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following:

```
if (oldValue && (oldValue <= 999))
```

But it seems this does not work if the number is 0.  Is there a correct Javascript way to do this check?

Comment: Isn't 0 also < 999? So you could only check for < 999.

Comment: sorry. just realized that and changed the title. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, You want between 0 and 998... then why are you doing `<=` 999?

Comment: What do you think `if (oldValue)` is doing?

Comment: FYI: The number 0 is 'falsy' in JavaScript, which is why your first check fails.  As others have suggested, you need an equality operator such as >= 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that it is equal to or over 0, less than or equal to 998, and that it is a number:

```
if (!isNaN(oldValue) && oldValue >= 0 && oldValue <= 998)
```

Comment: I think its more logical if the ordering is the other way around, first check if !isNaN, and then proceed with actual value checks, because the comparisons work from left to right, and if the first one fails, the others won't continue. This way you have two invalid checks for NaN types.

Comment: True. It's interesting to see how you thought months ago.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(oldvalue > 0 && oldvalue < 998){} //if you don't want to include 0 or 998
```

and

```
if(oldvalue >= 0 && oldvalue <= 998){} //if you do want to include 0 and 998
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if he/she wants to include the 0 when he/she says 'between'. I edited my response for both.

Answer (score 2):

This should be ok:

```
if(oldvalue >= 0 && oldvalue <999)
```